# How do I know a paper is indexed by SCI or ISTP from the query result of Web of Science?

Tags: web-of-science

I learnt from a blog ([here](http://www.weibo.com/p/230418631a4cc40102vdf8?pids=Pl_Official_CardMixFeedv6__4&feed_filter=1), IN CHINESE) that we can tell a paper indexed by SCI or ISTP via *IDS Number*. More specifically,

- SCI: IDS Number beginning with digits, such as `334VK`
- ISTP: IDS Number beginning with alphabets, such as `BF1NB`

**Is it correct**?

As an example, I attach the full record of a paper ([here](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/CitedFullRecord.do?product=WOS&colName=WOS&SID=T24ms3frY9OPEzmLgXj&search_mode=CitedFullRecord&isickref=WOS:000088206200002)),

```
Record 1 of 1
Title: Network information flow
Author(s): Ahlswede, R (Ahlswede, R); Cai, N (Cai, N); Li, SYR (Li, SYR); Yeung, RW (Yeung, RW)
Source: IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON INFORMATION THEORY  Volume: 46  Issue: 4  Pages: 1204-1216  DOI: 10.1109/18.850663  Published: JUL 2000  
Times Cited in Web of Science Core Collection: 3430
Total Times Cited: 3843
Usage Count (Last 180 days): 6
Usage Count (Since 2013): 90
Cited Reference Count: 14
Abstract: We introduce a new class of problems called network information flow which is inspired by computer network applications. Consider a point-to-point communication network on which a number of information sources are to be mulitcast to certain sets of destinations. We assume that the information sources are mutually independent. The problem is to characterize the admissible coding rate region. This model subsumes all previously studied models along the same line. In this paper, we study the problem with one information source, and we have obtained a simple characterization of the admissible coding rate region. Our result can be regarded as the Max-flow Min-cut Theorem for network information flow. Contrary to one's intuition, our work reveals that it is in general not optimal to regard the information to be multicast as a "fluid'' which can simply be routed or replicated. Rather, by employing coding at the nodes, which we refer to as network coding, bandwidth can in general be saved. This finding may have significant impact on future design of switching systems.
Accession Number: WOS:000088206200002
Language: English
Document Type: Article; Proceedings Paper
Conference Title: IEEE International Symposium on Information Theory
Conference Date: AUG 16-22, 1998
Conference Location: MIT, CAMBRIDGE, MASSACHUSETTS
Conference Sponsors: IEEE, Informat Theory Soc, Natl Sci Fdn, NASA, USN, Off Naval Res, AT&T, Motorola, Qualcomm, Lucent Technol, Bell Lab Innovat
Conference Host: MIT
Author Keywords: diversity coding; multicast; network coding; switching; multiterminal source coding
KeyWords Plus: MULTILEVEL
Addresses: Univ Bielefeld, Fak Math, D-33501 Bielefeld, Germany. 
Chinese Univ Hong Kong, Dept Informat Engn, Hong Kong, Hong Kong, Peoples R China.
Reprint Address: Ahlswede, R (reprint author), Univ Bielefeld, Fak Math, D-33501 Bielefeld, Germany.
Author Identifiers:
Author  ResearcherID Number ORCID Number
WANG, HUAN  A-1155-2009      
Publisher: IEEE-INST ELECTRICAL ELECTRONICS ENGINEERS INC
Publisher Address: 345 E 47TH ST, NEW YORK, NY 10017-2394 USA
Web of Science Categories: Computer Science, Information Systems; Engineering, Electrical & Electronic
Research Areas: Computer Science; Engineering
IDS Number: 334VK
ISSN: 0018-9448
29-char Source Abbrev.: IEEE T INFORM THEORY
ISO Source Abbrev.: IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory
Source Item Page Count: 13
```

Comment: You have to make sure that you are searching the paper of the intended Journal, not the paper which cites that work. This is sometimes misleading.